# Magento SOAP login error

Tags: magento, soap

I have configured Magento SOAP api to connect it with my android app, customers can login from android app into magento. The problem I am facing is when I send the request it shows the error - "Session expired".

this is my API.php file

```
    <?php

// app/code/local/Anaqa/Customapimodule/Model/Login/Api.php
class Anaqa_Customapimodule_Model_Customerlogin_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract {

    public function customerEntry($email) {        
        #Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($website);
        #        // Init a Magento session. This is super ultra important
        #Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

        // $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
        // We get an instance of the customer model for the actual website
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

        // Load the client with the appropriate email
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        return $customer;
    }
        /*
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
        $client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
        $session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
        $result = $client->call($session, 'product.list');
        $client->endSession($session);


        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($website);
        // Init a Magento session. This is super ultra important
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session');

        // $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
        // We get an instance of the customer model for the actual website
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

        // Load the client with the appropriate email
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);

        // Get a customer session
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $session->loginById($customer->getId());
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            return $session->getSessionId();
        } else {
            return null;
        } 
    } */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the customer/session model to access the customer.

```
$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

The wrinkle here is in order for magento to access the session data it needs to know the customer is logged in, otherwise you won't be able to return the customer data with the session data.